# Installing TkTreectrl on OSX

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, dylib

I installed TkTreeCtrl 2.4.1 (written in c), as well as TkTreectrl 1.0 ( written in python), which wraps the original c library.

When I try to create any treectrl objects in Python, I get the error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package treectrl
```

I'm pretty new to Python, but I'd guess that the Python wrapper code can't find the c library.

When I installed TkTreeCtrl(c) it installed itself in '/usr/lib/treectrl2.4.1' as a .dylib file.

I've never used a .dylib before, but some googling told me to add the directory it was in to the environment variable 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'.

I did that, but no luck. I'm not sure I'm even know what my problem is, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm running Lion and Python 2.7. Python was installed using MacPorts.

Comment: Which version of OS X? Which Python interpreter?

Comment: I added my particulars. Just out of curiosity, does a commenter get notified when a question has been edited?

Comment: (I don't think so but a commenter gets notified when a new comment is added.)  Are you sure you used (to install) and are now using the MacPorts Python 2.7 and not the Apple-supplied Python 2.7?  The latter is at `/usr/bin/python2.7` and, by default, `/usr/bin/python`; the former, at `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.  Depending on how you've set your shell PATH environment variable and whether you've used the MacPorts `port select python` command, the plain `python` command might get you either (or something else).  Also, installing into `/usr/lib` is not good; that's a dir managed by OS X.

Comment: `$ which python` gets me `/opt/local/bin/python`, and `$ python --version` gets me `Python 2.7.2`. As for installing into `/usr/lib', that's just where it went when I ran make install. Is it bad to install there for any functional reason, or is it just poor form? I tried copying the .dylib to other directories (such as the same directory as Treectrl.py) without any success.

Comment: It's bad because it's easy to inadvertently replace Apple-supplied files which can brick your system. Also you may find your files deleted at any time when Apple issues a System Update. In general, don't install anything in `/System/Library` or anywhere in `/usr` *except* `/usr/local`.

Comment: Just as a tip. Try to avoid MacPorts, especially for installing python. Whenever you can, use Homebrew in stead of MacPorts, and use the system provided Python in stead of the MacPorts one. This has caused me too much trouble in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For its Python ports, MacPorts currently builds and installs its own X11-based Tcl and Tk ports.  It looks like you would need to be careful when building TkTreeCtrl to specify the correct locations to `./configure` for the MacPorts provided Tcl, Tk, and X11 libraries and include files.  See `./configure --help` for the names of the options.  You should find the libraries and include files under `/opt/local/`, the default install location for MacPorts files.

There may be an easier option, though.  It appears that the ActiveTcl distributions for Tcl/Tk include TkTreeCtrl.  If you use a Python that links with ActiveTcl, you would just need to install the Python TkTreectrl module, which is straightforward.  On Lion, a free (though not open source) download of ActiveTcl 8.5 is available [here](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) which will automatically be used with the python.org 2.7.2 64-bit installer for OS X available [here](http://www.python.org/getit/).  ActiveState also has its own Python distribution for OS X.  There's more information about some of the quirks of Python and Tcl/Tk on OS X [here](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/).  Note that the ActiveTcl is a more native implementation on OS X; it is not X11-based.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work using ActiveTcl, but to do so I have to switch from MacPorts python. This wouldn't be a big deal, except that `sudo port select python python27-apple` still points to my MacPorts version for some reason. To get it to use the other python, I change my path so that MacPorts comes after everything else, which   isn't good in the long run.